# Identify and Convert to Numeric/Integer

Tags: r, data.table

I have a situation where I need to look at character data, and convert to numeric or integer. I need to perform this operation on a data.table and it needs to be sofastthatIdontnoticeit when working with a data.table that has ~1000 columns and 1e6 rows. There's a lot of missing, or sparse data so that is a confounding element.

`fread` from the `data.table` package does this incredibly quickly and is well tested from a csv file (amoung other options).

Is there a way to apply the column identification used in `fread` to an existing `data.table`?

Otherwise, here's the approach I was considering (which is still too slow):

Dummy Data:

```
library(data.table)

size = 1e6
resample <- function(x,size = 1e6) sample(x,size,replace = TRUE)

text <- c("Canada","Peru","Australia",
          "Angola","France","", NA_character_)
text2 <- c("Oh Canada.","Arriba Peru.",
           "Australia?","Vive la France.")
numerics <- rnorm(1e6)

dt <- data.table(
  id = as.character(1:1e6),
  i1 = resample(c(as.character(c(0:5,NA)),"")), # sometimes just blank
  i2 = resample(c(as.character(c(100:500,NA)))),
  n1 = as.character(round(rnorm(1e6),3)),
  t1 = resample(text),
  t2 = resample(text2)
)

str(dt)
```

My approach so far, is to use `grep` to test the columns for alpha, and a literal `.` and then write a short function to apply `as.*` as identified.

```
decide <- data.frame(
  vars = names(dt),
  character = unlist(lapply(dt, function(x) length(grep("[a-z]",x)))),
  numeric = unlist(lapply(dt, function(x) length(grep("[.]",x))))
)

what_is_it <- function(character, numeric) {
  if(character == 0 & numeric == 0) {
    return("as.integer")
  }
  if(character > 0) {
    return("as.character")
  } 
  if(numeric > 0 & character == 0) {
    return("as.numeric")
  }
}

decide$fun <- apply(decide[-1], 1, function(x) what_is_it(x[1],x[2]))

for(var in decide$vars) {
  fun <- get(decide$fun[decide$vars == var])
  dt[, (var) := fun(get(var))]
  dt[]
}
```

`system.time(source("https://gist.githubusercontent.com/1beb/183511b51d615751860204344a02c799/raw/91fcee73f24596ac6bdec00edaad944b5b1b7713/quick_convert.R"))`

Running at about 3.5 seconds on my machine, but for only 7 columns.

Comment: `type.convert` might be useful here

Comment: `system.time(for (j in names(dt) set(dt, j = j, value = type.convert(dt[[j]])))` 0.79 seconds. Not bad. Should be an answer tho!

Answer (score -1, accepted):

As provided by user20650. The answer is `type.convert`